# Can I visit a doctor in France, and pay for myself, after I leave France?

Tags: france, health-care, health-system

Background: I have been living in France for 2 years and will be here on a scientist visa for another year. One year from now, I will move to an asian country for work for 3 years. I'm considering getting a contraceptive implant which lasts for 3 years, so I don't have to worry about getting it prescribed in the next country I'm moving to (the kind I currently use is not available there, and finding something that works well may be challenging). However, if I get it a few months before leaving France, I will need to have it removed/reinserted a few months before I leave my new country. My new country does not provide/have this implant.

I will be spending some time in France intermittently, for work reasons, and to visit my French partner during my stay abroad.

*Can I see my previous doctor in France, when I live abroad and am visiting, to have a procedure done, without current access to CPAM*? Obviously I would pay for the costs of the procedure and the visits, I just want to make sure it's actually possible for a non-EU national to have non-emergency medical treatment in France when they are not currently resident there.

Comment: Have you asked the doctor?  In addition to the question you've asked here, I'd also ask how important it is to remove the thing promptly at 36 months.  Maybe it would be fine to leave it in for a few months longer, and maybe being able to delay its removal would be useful to you if moving to another country proves logistically challenging or if you'd be moving back to France and would then be able to have its removal paid for by the French system.

Comment: I plan to ask the doctor about that, and that's also why I'm going to get it a bit early - if there's a problem and I can't get it removed I'd be a bit screwed. Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, in general, there's no reason you can't make a non-emergency office visit to a specialist if you're non-resident and can pay up front.  It's just a question of getting it scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic question is : can I get access to a doctor for a non-emergency treatment in France when I'm a visiting non-EU national.

The answer is yes. (In particular if you don't intend to get some social security compensation as you explicitly mentioned).

Depending on the technical aspect of the treatment you wish to require, that might be more or less easy (easier if the treatment can be executed in the doctor's cabinet than if it requires going to a hospital).

Will your current doctor be ready to take an appointment with you in three years from now is a question you should ask him/her. You should also ask about what to expect in terms of cost.

Can such an appointment (or several if needed) be settled to fit your travel period in France is also something to take into account.

Comment: It's generally an office visit, not a hospital thing. Thanks!